# Running python script as soon as I boot my system(Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, scripts, python3

I want to run python script for two cases:

- as soon as the system boots
- as soon as when it wakes from sleep.

I have tried various options but none worked correctly. Can anyone suggest appropriate commands for these two cases?

Comment: What are these optons you have tried?

Comment: tried to run as provided in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: Now you're trying to do two things so you need to say which one of those things didn't work and which of the options there didn't. For the first option a possible answer may be there (perhaps your not doing it right), for the second none there will work as is!